# Partial converse to fact about isomorphic finite groups and their representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

If two finite groups are isomorphic then, they have the same irreducible characters (if $G_1\cong G_2$, we must send elements in a conjugacy class of $G_1$ to elements of the corresponding class in $G_2$ so that characters take on the same values).  The converse of this statement is false (Counterexample: $D_4\ncong Q_8$ but have the same character table). But is there a partial converse that is true? Put another way, are there conditions we can impose on two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ so that they are nessesarily isomorphic if they have the same character table? For example:

**Conjecture**: If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are finite simple nonabelian groups, and if $G_1$ and $G_2$ have the same character table, then $G_1\cong G_2$.

I am not sure if this question has any research value--I am but a lowly undergrad and was just wondering about this. I am looking for the strongest partial converse possible, but interested in any conditions people can think of.

Comment: I mean, an obvious condition would be if both $G_1$ and $G_2$ were abelian, but I assume you really want something more sophisitcated?

Comment: Yes, would wants something more interesting. But this is certainly true

Comment: A slightly more sophisticated example is a recent paper (I forget who it's by), that says that if $G$ is a finite group which has the same first column of its character table (degrees of irreps) as some $S_n$, then it must be $S_n$. But, this is hard result.

Comment: I found the paper, it is due to Tong-Viet: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.3939.pdf Notice, in particular, it requires the classification theorem.

Comment: Surprising result! Thanks for the paper..I will try to get through the proofs

Comment: I would advise against that honestly. This is a very long, arduous paper which relies heavily on case analysis coming from the classification theorem. If you are a "lowly undergraduate" as you say, then it might take you a good bit of time to even understand the groups coming from the classification theorem. That said, if it really does interest you so much, I would at least try talking to a professor about it.

Comment: I was just fascinated when I realized that the quaternion and dihedral-4 group have the same character table. I was dying to figure out what is special about them--what is really going on

Comment: Matt R There is a lot of information coming from the character table, including, for example, the normal subgroups (the center being distinguished) etc. What would shock me first is more that these two groups have exactly the same statistics in all of these categories.